# Can a finite number have an uncountable infinite amount of non-zero terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, $e=\dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+\dfrac{1}{4!}+\cdots$ has infinite terms when treated with this form, but it is a countable one, because the cardinality of natural numbers is countably infinite, and my question is if a number can have uncountably infinite terms. Thanks.

My thought is that it is impossible because it must be valid to enumerate the terms, which in uncountably infinites you cannot. Is this true? I need some aclarations.

Edit:

I only need non-zero terms, as sugested in the comments, and the number the terms sum to has to be a finite number.

Comment: If you mean, can a number be the sum of an uncountably infinite number of other numbers, then integrals in calculus are vaguely a good analogy.

Comment: Let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is a nonnegative integer and $0$ otherwise. Then
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb R} \frac{f(n)}{n!}=e$$
Has uncountably many terms. Perhaps you mean *nonzero* terms?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being poorly received - it's a very reasonable thing to ask.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree... I've already upvoted it, don't blame me. :P

Comment: All sums of uncountably many positive terms must diverge (that's because at least one of the buckets $(1,\infty), (\frac 12,1],(\frac 13,\frac 12],\cdots$ must contain infinitely many terms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Royden, pge 38, problem 20, part a, is to show that, if $E$ is a set of positive (nonzero) numbers, then
$$ \sum_{x \in E} x  < \infty $$
only if $E$ is countable.

The problem begins: Let $E$ be a set of positive real numbers. We define $\sum_{x \in E} x$  to be $\sup_{F \in \mathcal F} s_F,$ where $\mathcal F$ is the collection of finite subsets of $E$ and $s_F$ is the (finite) sum of the elements of $F.$

Comment: It actually is a great answer to the question.

Comment: What if $E$ is **not** a set of positive non-zero terms? (The OP states non-zero terms, so they can be negative as well)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: If E contained negative terms, then using the supplied definition, your sum would be $\sum_{x \in E \cap (0, \infty)} x$ (where summing over the empty set yields $0$), as using negative terms in the sum is strictly non-optimal. Forcing negative terms into the sum is tricky, as it would require additional assumptions to make the sum well-defined. If you force the negative and positive sums to be finite, it's not very interesting. If not, then you run into the problems of conditional convergence of series. Introducing an order would just reduce the problem back to series anyway.